# Python pygame mixer music detect if ended

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I'm making a simple music player with a pygame mixer, and I have to know if the music ended. Is there any easy way?

Something like this:

```py
if pygame.mixer.music.is_ended: #like this!
    pass
```

Comment: [`pygame.mixer.get_busy`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html#pygame.mixer.get_busy)

Answer (score 1):

**If you just want to confirm the music and yu can just simply perform a test in the terminal**

```
if pygame.mixer.music.is_ended: #like this!
    print('yes')
```

** you can further add a second program ,if you want to do something else you can also do the same.......**

**Here is a example if you want to continue music till the end of the program**

```
mixer.music.load('background.wav')
mixer.music.play(-1)
```

**Here -1 will repeat the song again and again**